# Array of Pointers to object declared within a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So My Question is: I want to know how to delete the (accounts pointer array) so that I can fill the array back in with the contents of my dummyA array. I tried `delete[]` and `delete accounts[j]` with a for loop, but to no avail I keep getting an error: `_ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));` Honestly, I have no Idea what this means..
Upon research, my best guess is that my problem is that I'm deleting my array more than once but I don't know how..Essentially,my accounts array of pointers to new objects has an irrelevant object in the middle of the array, soooo I made a dummy to place all relevant objects into with the goal of erasing all objects in accounts then replacing the objects with the objects inside of dummy,I want to save memory and try to be efficient.. Any Takers??
        // Header File
    **ifndef H_ChartOfAccounts**
    **define H_ChartOfAccounts**
    **include string**
    **using namespace std;**

```
const int size = 100;


class cOfA
{
protected:
int actNumber;
string actName;
int actType;
static cOfA* accounts[size];<Dynamic Array of Pointers to Object "In Question"
static int totalAccounts;

public:
cOfA();
virtual ~cOfA();
void getAccount();
static void createAccount();
static void addAccount();
static void delAccount();
static void displayAccount();
void saveAccount();
};

**endif**
//>Implementation File For Above Header File
void cOfA :: delAccount()
{
int searchItem;
char ch;

cout<<"\nEnter the Account Number that you want to delete: ";
cin>>searchItem;

for ( int j = 0; j < totalAccounts; j++ )
{
    if ( accounts[j]->actNumber == searchItem )
    {
        cout<<"\nDo you want to delete this account: \n";
        cout<< accounts[j]->actName<<" / ";
        cout<< accounts[j]->actNumber<<" / ";
        cout<< accounts[j]->actType<<endl;
        cin>>ch;

        if(ch == 'y')
        {
            accounts[j]->actName = " ";
            accounts[j]->actNumber = 0;
            accounts[j]->actType = 0;
            totalAccounts--;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\nEnter the Account Number you want to delete: ";
            cin>>searchItem;
        }
    }//end if
}// for loop

cOfA* dummyA[size];
int l = 0;

    for ( int k = 0;k < totalAccounts+1; k++ )
    {
        if( accounts[k]->actNumber != 0 )
        {
            dummyA[l] = new cOfA;
           *dummyA[l] = *accounts[k];
           l++;
        }

    }//end for loop


delete[] accounts;//<--"When I compile, I get My Error Here"

//Break Statement:"  _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)); "


int j = 0;
while ( j < totalAccounts )
{
    accounts[j] = new cOfA;
    *accounts[j] = *dummyA[j];
    j++;
}//end while loop
delete[] dummyA;


}
```

Comment: First, fix your indentation. Second, make a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: you can edit your post instead of writing pieces of code in comments.

Comment: Third: Bad truncation of code

Answer (score 0):

In comments you said that `accounts` is:

```
static cOfA* accounts[size];
```

**Then you should not be `delete[]`ing it at all, as it was not dynamically-allocated.**

You must use `delete[]` only on things that you `new[]`'d.

Speaking of which, I don't see any `delete` statements for those pointer *elements*.

In general I'd try to get rid of *all* of your pointer usage, because it doesn't look necessary to me.

Comment: thank everyone for the feedback im new to this and learning if that wasnt obvious..lol.. I will work on indentations and formatting as I get used to this...

Comment: @user3163375: Next time please work on it _before_ hitting "Submit". :) Welcome.

Comment: I am confused, 'accounts[j]' is a dynamic array right? A dynamic array is created during the execution of the program.I declared it ' <type>*<pointerName>[size];' But It dont actually allocate memory until I use "new" to create it.Since I used "new" to create,why cant I use "delete[]" to erase it?

Answer (score 0):

So There are 2 problems with this code that are responsible for the errors. 1: Basic rule of static variables states: You cannot declare and place a value into a static variable in the class you are declaring it in. I declared the **static variable accounts** array and put a value into the array called **size** . 2: I shallow copied one pointer array into another,so when I deleted **accounts**, I also deleted **dummyA**. Instead I couldve used a copy constructor and declared an array of pointers outside the class, or Used pointer to pointer methods to sort the pointer array.These are the solutions I found to be helpful. I chose to use pointer to pointer functions to sort my array and save memory, now I can use delete when I need to and no more errors.

```
  int j;
int k;

for ( j = 0; j < totalAccounts ; j++ )
{
    for ( k = j + 1; k < totalAccounts; k++ )
    {
        if ( accounts[j] == NULL )
            accounts[j] = accounts[k];
        if ( accounts[k] == NULL )
            continue;
        order ( accounts + j, accounts + k );
    }
}

}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void cOfA :: order ( cOfA** pp1, cOfA** pp2 )
{
if ( (pp1) == NULL )
    return;
if ( (pp2) == NULL )
    return;
if ( (*pp1)->actNumber > (*pp2)->actNumber )
{
    cOfA* temp = *pp1;
    *pp1 = *pp2;
    *pp2 = temp;
}

}
```